# What is the best architecture for images folder structure for the best Tomcat server preformance?

Tags: java, tomcat, file-io, filesystems

I use neo4j database to store images id`s, but in which way it would be better to structure my folders that file system can access them the fastest way.

Store all images in the single folder

Create new folders when the original reach some kind of max size

Store all images in individual folder for each user, place, service e.t.c.

Or else...

Comment: This is too-broad to ask on Stack Overflow. Please [ask].

Comment: @Tunaki, yes but there are like ten, or so, almost the same questions and none of them were even vaguely answered, so i would be grateful even for a few hints where to look for it

Comment: And by the way, there are Related question to this in which guy asks: What is the difference between tomcat and jBoss. And it have like 200+ rating, in what way my question is more broad than his.

Answer (score 2):

Serving a file is low-level but Java is interpreted from the VM. You better use a apache who serves the images low-level and a tomcat for the application connected via AJP to the apache.